# Is there a Managed Wifi API that includes the Wi-Fi Direct functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wifi-direct

I installed the Managed Wifi API (managedwifi) using Visual Studio's NuGet, and it only uses the Wlan object, which only allows me to retrieve accessible Wifi addresses:
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=managedwifi

This page states that "**The Native Wifi API contains a set of functions that support the use of Wi-Fi Direct for desktop apps.**"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/about-the-wi-fi-direct-api

Is there a C# library that allows me to use the Native Wifi functions that are missing from the Managed Wifi API (i.e. the Wi-Fi Direct functions)?

Or is there a working C# sample that shows how a Windows Form app can use the Wi-Fi Direct functions?

Comment: The URL listed in the previous comment is for a 3rd party app without source code. Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you would need to create your own .Net wrapper for the new Native WiFi API.

Comment: Do it your-self then, not too hard but takes time.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to use the WinRT APIs: http://blog.plasticscm.com/2016/09/using-peerfinder-from-console-wi-fi.html

Comment: The previous comment (WinRT APIs) refers to code that is 4 years old, and was built for Windows 8, It does not compile in Windows 10.